# nginx rewrite rules http://example.org/img?src=A to A?

Tags: nginx

My url format :
   http://example.org/img?src=http://a.com/logo.png

I want nginx to rewrite this request to http://example.org/logo.png
(not url redriect)

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `src` argument is available as the `$arg_src` variable, however, you will need to use an `if` block to extract the part that you need. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on using `if`.

For example (and you will need to adapt the regex to your specific needs):

```
location = /img {
    if ($arg_src ~ \w(?<src>/\w.*)$) {
        rewrite ^ $src last;
    }
}
```

See nginx documentation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html) and a useful resource for regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).